# How To Call View Name In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

My view's name is Favourite-Items.cshtml.
I am calling my view from controller as this:

```
    public ActionResult Favourite_Items(int id)
    {
        var t_Favourite_Items = db.Favourite_Items.Where(t => t.UserID == id);
        return View("Favourite-Items", t_Favourite_Items );
    }
```

But i have error as this:

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Can you help please?

Comment: Did you put the [HttpGet] Attribute before the method signature ? This error is not that of a view page not found.

Comment: Are you trying to run the site directly from visual studio, or this is hosted on your local iis? as @Mik said, this is not related to not finding the view.

Comment: I use iis express. Yes i added [HttpGet] but still get same message.When i change view name as Favorite_Items then its ok but if view name is 'Favorite-Items' then i get error.

Comment: My problem continues :(